# Allow me to hide the starred messages

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-stars

While traveling, I often have to resort to a particularly tiny screen on my laptop. SE chat is somewhat frustrating to use because a lot of my rooms I'm on are hidden by the starred messages.

I don't really care so much about the starred messages. At least not as much as I care about the rooms I'm on.

[image]

So when I click the link "show 13 more", it does show them, but the list is cut off :(

Comment: With a low enough resolution, you see nothing at all. I think on my 1280x720 screen (hooked up to a TV), I can only see one message there, so it gets bad real fast.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Awesome! Then I don't need to *hide* anything either!